# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) while loading image in img element

Tags: javascript, html

I want to **load** image while **selecting** it from `file picker` dialog.

Code given below but it does not load the image in `img` tag

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <img id="upload-file-info" />
  <form action="#">
    <label class="btn btn-primary" for="my-file-selector">
     <input id="my-file-selector" type="file" style="display:none" onchange="$('#upload-file-info').attr('src', this.files[0].name)">Click to select image
    </label>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: just check with alert the file name in  `onchange="alert(this.files[0].name);" `

Comment: src attribute us going to look for a url (xhr request). You'll need to look into HTML canvas in order to display actual stored-in-code files.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want preview of image in `img` tag.

You have to change `src` of `img` to data URL of image:

```
$('#upload-file-info').attr('src', window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <img id="upload-file-info" />
  <form action="#">
    <label class="btn btn-primary" for="my-file-selector">
     <input id="my-file-selector" type="file" style="display:none" onchange="$('#upload-file-info').attr('src', window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]))">Click to select image
    </label>
  </form>
</div>
```

The server gives 404 error because `input` element doesn't add image files to server. Your selected image is saved in browser only.